# Mongoose - set a field from its value plus an existing field of the schema

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Using `mongoose` with `node.js`

I have `users` in my database, and every user has some `projects`.

I need to make projects `unique` for every user, but repeated for different users.

Let's say I have `userA & userB` and their projects are like that:

```
UserA = { "todo-list", "notes" }

UserB = { "edu-platform", "todo-list" }
```

I need `userA` to be able to add `userB` projects and the opposite, but `userA` cannot add a project name like any of his own projects.

Note, All projects are in the same collection.

---

I know that I can use the `set` in the mongoose schema, and I can use `this.key` to use another key of the same document.

But can I use `this.project_name` to add to the provided value:

```
let ProjectSchema = new mongoose.schema({
    username: "",
    project_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        set: () => (this.username + "-" + this.project_name)
    }
})
```

or there's something else correct?!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) to declare a ProjectSchema (like you have) and then in your UserSchema, you'll need to have one of the properties be an array of ProjectSchemas, like this:

```js
...
projects: [ProjectSchema],
...
```

Mongoose doesn't have a built in way to enforce uniqueness within an array at the schema level, but it does have ways to only add a new project to an array if it doesn't already exist in that array. You can use the [`$addToSet` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#op._S_addToSet) when adding a value to an array to prevent a project from being added if it already exists in the array.

Comment: I already know that approach, and I already has a projects array in the `user schema` but I don't need to put the project itself inside the `user schema`, instead I want to put the `_ids` of the project documents belong to this user. The question is about updating the value entered to the field before putting it in the database?! 